# Update Orphan Records using Join

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I got 2 tables as below.  Ideally `Table2.C1` is a foreign key of `Table1.C1` however that foreign key was not setup initially.  We are not able to setup the foreign key now because there are some orphan records exists in Table2.  We want to UPDATE those orphan records column to NULL.

Note: I do not want use any sub/nested query

```
Table1
--------
| C1   |
--------
| 1    |
| 2    |
| 3    |
| 4    |
|------|

Table2
---------------
| C1   |  C3  |
---------------
| 1    |  A   |
| 1    |  B   |
| 8    |  C   |
| 9    |  D   |
| 2    |  E   |
|------|------|
```

I want to UPDATE `Table2.C1` to NULL for the records `8` and `9`.

Comment: You asked another quesiton about deleting orphan rows. Do you think that updating is really so different that you couldn't use a similar solution?

Comment: @Barmer Please don't assume that I am trying to abuse here... I spent almost 3 to 4 hours and then only finally decided to post the question.

Comment: You posted the second question 35 minutes after the first. That's not hours.

Comment: @Barmar sorry, what I mean is I spent for both the queries and enough to get answers. Apologies if you see as different.

Comment: My complaint is you got an answer to the question, and apparently didn't make any effort to try the same solution for your second problem, even though it's almost identical. 30 minutes after getting the answer you posted the second question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use query like below:

```
UPDATE Table2 SET C1 = NULL WHERE C1 NOT IN ( SELECT Table1.C1 FROM Table1 )
```

Note: SQL optimizator should optimize this query through using of JOIN operators. So for such simple query doesn't matter that you use nested subquery or through join like this:

```
UPDATE Table2 SET C1 = NULL FROM Table2 
LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.C1 = Table1.C1 
WHERE Table1.C1 IS NULL
```

Execution plans for both query on big tables should be the same

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you want do this without a subquery, since you can't do a JOIN on rows in table1 that **don't exist**...